# How to return a custom, non model value with serializer in Django?

Tags: python, django, serialization

I'd like to return a custom value from my serializer. I'm getting authentication tokens for the user and would like to return them as part of the registration process. At the moment I'm returning the user object and I don't know how to add the tokens into the return object as the tokens are not a part of my User model. Here's the serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ['password', 'is_active', 'staff', 'admin', 'last_login']

    def create(self, validated_data):

        userName= validated_data['userName']
        id= validated_data['id']
        dateOfBirth = validated_data['dateOfBirth']
        gender = validated_data['gender']
        height = validated_data['height']
        weight = validated_data['weight']

        user = User(userName=userName, id=id, dateOfBirth=dateOfBirth, gender=gender, height=height, weight=weight)
        user.set_password("")
        user.save()

        try:
            jwt_token = get_tokens_for_user(user)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'User does not exists'
            )
 
        return user
```

userName, id, dateOfBirth, height and weight are fields in my User Model. Now I'd like to return also the `jwt_token` from the `create` -method to be used in my `views.py`, is it possible to add it to the user object without editing the Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
try:
  jwt_token = get_tokens_for_user(user)
except User.DoesNotExist:
  raise serializers.ValidationError(
    'User does not exists'
  )

created_data = {
  'token_access': jwt_token, # note that jwt_token is dict
  'user': UserSerializer(user).data,
}
return created_data
```

But honestly I recommend you not to mix user and token logic and move this piece into view section:

```
try:
   jwt_token = get_tokens_for_user(user)
except User.DoesNotExist:
   raise serializers.ValidationError(
     'User does not exists'
   )
```

And then write token and user in `Response`

Comment: Accepting this as an answer as I did this like suggested, moved the token logic into `views.py`.

Answer (score 3):

You can return a tuple including the `user` and the `jwt_token` like this:

```
return (user, jwt_token)
```

and something like this in the `views.py`:

```
instance, token = serializer.save()
```

But if you are using any predefined Veiwsets or Mixins ***be careful*** when you pass them this serializer.

Hope this helped.